# Proving Group-ness of a given peculiar set of reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Take $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $G_n = \{a + b\sqrt{n} | a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}
.$ I want to show that $G_n$ is a group with respect to addition.

Closure is relatively easy to prove, since
$$(a + b\sqrt{n}) + (c + d\sqrt{n}) = (a+c) + (b+d)\sqrt{n},$$
and identity is likely to be $0 + 0\sqrt{n}.$ I was feeling a bit uncertain
about the inverse, since I would imagine it would be simply the coefficient
negation of $a+b\sqrt{n}$, but I am not entirely sure. I was also wondering if
I could get some help on proving that a similar set, $G_n = \{a+ib\sqrt{n}
| a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ was a group with respect to complex multiplication.
Any suggestions on these problems?

Comment: What do you mean by «the identity is *likely* $0+0\sqrt n$»? Haven't you checked?!

Comment: As for your second question: what exactly in what you did with the first subset does *not* work with the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned the identity is $0 + 0\sqrt{n}$ as: $$(a + b\sqrt{n}) + (0 + 0\sqrt{n}) = (a+0) + (b+0)\sqrt{n} = a + b\sqrt{n}$$

Similarly we can compute that the inverse of $a+b\sqrt{n}$ is $-a-b\sqrt{n}$

For the second case obviously we have that $1 + 0i\sqrt{n}$ is the identity. Now assume $a'+ib'\sqrt{n}$ is the inverse of $a+ib\sqrt{n}$. Then we have:

$$1 + 0i\sqrt{n} = (a+ib\sqrt{n})(a'+ib'\sqrt{n}) = (aa' - bb'n) + i(ab' + ba')\sqrt{n}$$

Equating the coefficients we have that:

$$\begin{cases} aa'-bb'n = 1 \\ ab'+ba' = 0 \end{cases}$$

Now just express $a'$ and $b'$ in terms of $a,b$ and $n$ to get the inverse and see whether it's in $G_n$ or not.

Comment: The second set contains zero, so it is quite difficilt for it to be a group with respect to multiplication...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|(a+ib\sqrt{n})(c+id\sqrt{n})|^2 = (a^2 + b^2 n)(c^2 + d^2 n)$.
If $n > 1$ and $b \ne 0$, there is no way to get $1$ on the right side.